# How many integers $m$ such that $9^m - m$ is divisible by $65$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How many integers $m$ such that $9^m - m$ is divisible by $65$ where $1\le m \le 1000$
> $\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}$

### My approach

Generally we want to solve:
$$ 9^m \equiv m \Mod{65} $$
From [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) we know that this is equivalent to:
$$ 9^m \equiv m \Mod{13} \wedge 9^m \equiv m \Mod{5} $$

1. After write some first elements from $9^m$ we see that
   $$ 9^m \text{ mod } 5 =  \begin{cases} 4 \text{ when m is odd} \\ 1 \text{ when m is even} \end{cases}$$
   so we are thinking about all numbers which have $6,9$ at first digit.
2. After write some first elements from $9^m$ we see that
   $$ 9^m \text{ mod } 13 =  \begin{cases} 9 \text{ when m = 3k+ 1} \\ 3\text{ when m = 3k+ 2} \\ 1\text{ when m = 3k} \end{cases}  $$
   we see that for $m=3k+1$ and for $m=3k+2$ there is no chance to have the same remainder. So we want every $m$ in form of $m=3k$ which is dividable by $13$. So we want each $m$ dividable by $39$. It will be:
   $$ 39,
   78,
   117,
   156,
   195,
   234,
   273,
   312,
   351,
   390,
   429,
   468,
   507,
   546,
   585,
   624,
   663,
   702,
   741,
   780,
   819,
   858,
   897,
   936,
   975
    $$
   We choose these number which pass condition in $(1)$ and we get
   $$39,
   156,
   429,
   546,
   819,
   936,
    $$

but this is wrong answer... It should be $16$ numbers...

Comment: I've edited your post for numbered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As $65=13\cdot5$

$3^3\equiv1\pmod{13}\implies9^3\equiv1\implies$ord$_{13}9=3$

and similarly ord$_59=2$

$\implies$ord$_{65}=[3,2]=6$

This is instantly available from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

So, there can be $12/2$ unique values of $9^m=3^{2m}$

namely  $0\le m<6$

$m\equiv0\pmod6,9^m\equiv1\pmod{65}$

So, for $m=6n,$

$9^m-m\equiv1-6n\pmod{65},n=11+65r,m=6(11+65r)$

For $m=6n+1$

$9^m-m\equiv9-(6n+1)\pmod{65}\iff3n\equiv4+65\iff n\equiv23,m=1+6(23+65r)$

Similarly check for $m=6n+2,6n+3,6n+4,6n+5$

Comment: Wish I could learn the mistake here!

Comment: not introducing your Carmichael function  to a lay audience? just a start.

Comment: @Roddy, Please find the updated post

Comment: got the downvote removed ( downvote wasn't me BTW)

Answer (score 2):

The mistake appears in (2), there are values for $m$ such that $m\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $m\equiv 9\mod 13$. By Chinese remainder theorem these are exactly all $m\equiv 22\mod 39$. You can handle the second and third case anaologously. Note that you don't want $m$ to be divisible by $13$ in the third case (as you stated), but $m\equiv 1\mod 13$.

Note also that you can combine these conditions with case (1), instead of writing all $m$ down and picking those which satisfy (1). For example, $m\equiv 22\mod 39$ and $m\equiv 6\mod 10$ is equivalent to $m\equiv 256\mod 390$, so you are left with only two values for $m\leq 1000$ here.

Comment: can you tell me why you got $22$ in that equation? $m\equiv 22\mod 39$?

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem says that there is exactly one $0\leq k<39$ such that $k\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $k\equiv 9\mod 13$ and all solutions are then of the form $k+l\cdot 39$. Now with such low numbers you can just guess $k$ (that's what I did) or you solve the equation $3a+1=13b+9$, i.e. $3a-13b=8$, which can be done with the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You mistook the possible residues $\bmod 13$.  Multiples of $39$ do not work (e.g. $9^{39}\not=39\bmod 13$), and there are non-multiples of $39$ that do.

Properly, powers of $9\bmod 13$ are given by $9^1\equiv 9, 9^2\equiv 3, 9^3\equiv 1$ and cyclic repetitions.  So $m\in\{1,3,9\}\bmod 13$ and for each of these residues, $m\bmod 3$ must have the right residue to match the cyclic pattern of powers:

$m\equiv 1\bmod 13$ AND $m\equiv 0\bmod 3$

$m\equiv 3\bmod 13$ AND $m\equiv 1\bmod 3$

$m\equiv 9\bmod 13$ AND $m\equiv 2\bmod 3$

Working through each possibility with CRT then renders $m\in\{16,27,35\}\bmod 39$, which you must "marry" with the correctly derived requirement that $n$ end in $6$ or $9$ base $10$.  For instance, $m\equiv 16\bmod 39$ gives $16, 406, 796$ ending in $6$ and $289, 679$ ending in $9$.  You get $16$ solutions in all among the three accepted residues $\bmod 39$.